# Laravel - Webpack - Generate static HTML file

Tags: html, laravel, webpack

**Would like to:**

Create a static HTML file from a view (so it should include all CSS and JS) using the technologies mentioned above (default Laravel installation)

**What I tried:**

- Simply injecting the content of the `app.js` into the `app.blade.php` file with the following code (done this for the `app.css` and it worked) but it only printed out the text of the JS file:

```html
<script defer>
    {!! file_get_contents(public_path('js/app.js')) !!}
</script>
```

- [static-generator package](https://github.com/davekelly/static-generator) => It is only for 4.2

Comment: why your view is named `app.blade.html` and not `app.blade.php`?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `<script src="{{ public_path('js/app.js') }}"/>`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sorry, it was just a typo

Comment: @TimLewis I built a single page application, which can work without reaching the server so I would like to make a downloadable (single HTML file) version of it. In that case the server should be reachable to serve the JS file's content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm production` (instead of `npm development`) and it will minify the assets, won't leave in comments and stuff and the first solution (simply injecting it into the HTML file will work)